# user_exists function using PDO connect to mysql

Tags: php, database, pdo

im still in the early learning stages, banging my head against walls looking for clues. Iv been reading the manual to no avail. Im building a user log in system based on the phpAcadamy tutorial 'Register & Login'. They use mysql_connect in the tutorial, but I am using a PDO connection to mysql.

i am making my first function, user_exists, which queries the username column of my table for names that match the POSTed $username, then returns a true or false if it is found.

here is my testing code:

```
$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "mholberg_skroovy";
$password   = "*omitted*";
$dbname     = "mholberg_skroovytest";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};", $username, $password);

function user_exists($username) {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT `users`.`username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; // ???
}

if (user_exists('junkomatic') === true) {
    echo 'exists';
}

die();
```

The if statement at the bottom should test the function above it. The line with ??? is the line that is obviously wrong. Im getting an error on the ',' Any input/explanation would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You definitely got your answer below, but I'm curious. What does return($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false; really do? (I haven't seen it before)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld in theory throw an error, there's a missing bracket anyway!

Comment: @bardoo - I tried to explain further more. I don't know what your actual code is doing, but I've answered how I may have done it (returning true when there is a user)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I think he got some tutorials and got confused with the `mysql_result`, maybe? In a query with a `count()` column, `mysql_result($query, 0) == 1` should work. `result` and `return` are similar :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems easy to fix, you just need to execute the prepared query before you can fetch anything from the result set.

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Where did the "$stmt" comes from? (I know that this is "$statement" in the docs, but the OP didn't use it) Why did this answer got accepted?!

Comment: @DiegoNunes it probably gave him the needed input to look up the rest by himself in the docs, i guess! conceptually that was the only part missing in the code! you cannot access a resultset without executing your statement!

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not use prepared statement. 
$db is not defined within the function so the code will generate an error.

You will have to do something like this instead:

```
function user_exists($db, $username) {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`idUser`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
    $query->execute(array(':username'=> $username));
    $cnt = $query -> fetch(); //Get actual count of users

    return $cnt >= 1 ? true : false; //This will return true if count is one or larger else it would return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not executing your query, that's why this isn't working proprely.
You can just add the execute command, just add

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `users`.`username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
$query->execute();
```